# Discord.JS Slash Command Error: "ExpectedConstraintError: Invalid string format"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Here is my code

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('Ping')
        .setDescription('Return my ping'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const message = await interaction.deferReply({
            fetchReply : true
        });

        const newMessage = `API Latency: ${client.ws.ping}\nClient Ping: ${message.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp}`
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: newMessage
        });

    }
}
```

And here is the console error

```
C:\Users\The Friesen Boy's\Desktop\georgebot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1564
      return regex.test(input) ? Result.ok(input) : Result.err(new ExpectedConstraintError(type, "Invalid string format", input, expected));
                                                               ^

ExpectedConstraintError: Invalid string format
    at Object.run (C:\Users\The Friesen Boy's\Desktop\georgebot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1564:64)
    at C:\Users\The Friesen Boy's\Desktop\georgebot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:142:66
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at StringValidator.parse (C:\Users\The Friesen Boy's\Desktop\georgebot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:142:29)
    at validateName (C:\Users\The Friesen Boy's\Desktop\georgebot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:782:17)
    at MixedClass.setName (C:\Users\The Friesen Boy's\Desktop\georgebot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:856:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\The Friesen Boy's\Desktop\georgebot\src\commands\tools\ping.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32) {
  constraint: 's.string.regex',
  given: 'Ping',
  expected: 'expected /^[\\p{Ll}\\p{Lm}\\p{Lo}\\p{N}\\p{sc=Devanagari}\\p{sc=Thai}_-]+$/u.test(expected) to be true'
}

Node.js v18.6.0
```

Does anyone know a fix to this? I could not find an answer. There is one other thread on this subject and it didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 3):

According to stack trace, 'Ping' seems to be an invalid command name. Have you tried using 'ping' (lowercase) as stated [in the docs](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/builders/docs/examples/Slash%20Command%20Builders.md)?

```js
new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ping')
```